# What is the best place on server to keep the creds and apikeys?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure

I need to know what are the best practices for, where and how to keep the db creds and like thirdparty api's key/tokens on server.

From security point of view.

Comment: Not on the server. Use secrets manager: https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager/

Comment: Azure has Key Vault for that

Comment: Ok, you people answered specific to the cloud technologies, what in case someone not using Azure or AWS cloud services?

Comment: @smkrn110 Take a look. Hope you would get Idea. If you still have any query feel free to share here in comment.

Comment: @smkrn110 If is it helpful would you kindly mark as answer to help the community. Thanks and happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

I think you would like to store your credential like API-Keys, Certificate, Passwords or anything related to sensitive information ensuring more security right?

Well, As you may know cloud applications and services use cryptographic keys and secrets to help keep information secure. 
For highly sensitive data, you should consider additional layers of protection for data. Encrypting data using a separate protection key prior to storage in [`Key Vault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-whatis) is worthwhile for example.

**Azure Key Vault:**

Azure Key Vault provides safeguards for following keys and secrets.for example, When you use Key Vault, you can `encrypt authentication keys`, `storage account keys`, `data encryption keys`, `.pfx files`, and `passwords by using keys` that are protected by `hardware security modules (HSMs)`.

**Key Vault reduce following problems:**

1. *Secret management*
2. *Key management*
3. *Certificate management*
4. *Store secrets backed by HSMs*
5. *Any Third party sensitive credentials*

You could check for more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-whatis)

**Access Your Key Vaults More securely**

You may need to access your key vault more securely because of its data sensitivity learn more  about [`Secure access to a key vault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-secure-your-key-vault)

**How secret and Certificate collaborate with azure key vault**

Also for key vault **`secret and certificate`** you can check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/about-keys-secrets-and-certificates)

**Azure key vault quick start**

Setting up and retrieve a secret from Azure Key Vault using the Azure portal you can quickly start from [`Microsoft official document for azure key vault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/quick-create-portal)

> **Note:** Now a days `azure key-vaults` become more popular among the big organizations and towards the developer as well to manage large scale
>   of security key , certification and many more. For more details I
>   would recommend to take a look official document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-whatis)

If you have any more query feel free to share. Thanks and happy coding!

Comment: Farid, actually I was expecting beside these two. If there were any or if not then Yes. I already looked AWS Secret Manager and Azure Vault too. THanks.

Comment: @smkrn110 I understand that. No worries man, I just asked it for the sake of community. No problem. Hope you have got your workaround. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Storing secrets on the server is not best practice.  If you are using AWS you can use [Secrets Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager) to securely manage your secrets.

Comment: I want to know what were the practices before these Key Management solution AWS SM or Azure Vault.